# Output Leaderboard with JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I am using the Scoreoid platform to implement a leaderboard. The following is my JSON response:

```
[{
    "Player": {
        "username": "TestPlayer",
        "email": "",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "platform": ""
    },
    "Score": {
        "score": "23",
        "created": "2012-07-13 22:06:46",
        "difficulty": "0",
        "platform": ""
    }
}]
```

Trying to format this JSON into a DIV, with this (which also contains my call):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $.post('scoreoid_proxy.php', {action:'curl_request', method:'getScores', response:'JSON'},
            function(data) {
            $.each(data.Player, function(i,Player){
                content = '<p>' + Player.username + '</p>';
                content += '<br/>';
                $(content).appendTo("#response");
                });
            });
        });
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
object is undefined
length = object.length,
```

Any help would be appreciated, I'm sure it's something simple I am missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is an array (of objects).

```
$.each(data, function(i, v){
    var Player = v.Player;
    var content = '<p>' + Player.username + '</p><br/>'
    $("#response").append(content);
});
```

**EDIT**: You need to tell jQuery that this is JSON, and that it needs to parse it.  That can be done by adding `'json'` as a parameter to `$.post` (after the callback).

```
$.post('scoreoid_proxy.php', {
    action: 'curl_request',
    method: 'getScores',
    response: 'JSON'
}, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, v) {
        var Player = v.Player;
        var content = '<p>' + Player.username + '</p><br/>'
        $("#response").append(content);
    });
}, 'json');
```

Comment: @Elisabeth: Check the edit I added to the answer.  Your JSON may not have been getting parsed.